# How to insert a circle above a letter in MATLAB text

Tags: latex, matlab-figure, symbols

in LaTeX, it would be something like

```
\overset{\circ}{K}
```

which will result in the letter K with a circle above it in the center (not on the right as a superscript). However, my question is, how can I do the same in MATLAB text, e.g. in figures' titles or labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this close enough?

```
figure(); title('$\mathop K\limits^ \circ$','interpreter','latex');
```

[image]